# Find the smallest value of $|20^m −9^n|$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is supposed to be solved using high school methods, I've been thinking about Bezout, but I don't know whether that'll work, or even how to use it in this scenario.

Edit: It was supposed to be $20^m$ and $9^n$, I mistyped.

Comment: If $|20^m-9^n|$ is small, then so is $|m\log20-n\log9|$, and so is $$\left|{\log20\over\log9}-{n\over m}\right|$$ so probably worth expanding $\log20/\log9$ in a continued fraction and looking at convergents.

Comment: Note also that $20^m-9^n$ is relatively prime to all divisors of $9$ and $20$, hence to all numbers less than $11$ except possibly $7$ (provided $m>0$ and $n>0$). So all you have to do is rule out $20^m-9^n=\pm7$, which you can do by considerations modulo $5$. Oh, you also have to rule out $\pm1$.

Comment: Gerry Myerson, you should write this as answer.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly $20^m-9^n=11$ has a solution.

Now suppose $20^m-9^n=t$ with $|t|<11$.

If we're allowed to use zero as an exponent, then we have $20^0-9^0=0$, so we'll assume zero is banned.

Then $t$ can't be divisible by $2$ or $5$, since $20^m$ is but $9^n$ isn't; similarly, $t$ can't be a multiple of $3$, since $9^n$ is but $20^m$ isn't. So the only possibilities are $t=\pm1,\pm7$.

Let $t=\pm1$, and work modulo $19$: we get $9^n\equiv0{\rm\ or\ }2\bmod{19}$. But this is impossible, since $9$ is a square modulo $19$, and $2$ isn't (and $0$ is absurd).

Let $t=\pm7$, and work modulo $5$. Then $-(-1)^n\equiv\pm2\bmod5$, which is impossible.

So, you can achieve $11$, and can't beat it.

Comment: How do you know for sure 11 is achieveable?

Comment: $m=n=1$, right?

Comment: oh, right. sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

An absolute value cannot be less than $0$.  Can you make the expression equal $0$?  If so, show how and you are done.

Comment: The question has changed now.